# How to configure Resharper 5.1's Test Runner to accept network shares?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, resharper

i have a project that lies on a network share. The test runner tries to run the tests but fails with an error message.

Unit Test Runner failed to load assembly:
JetBrains.ReSahrper.TaskRunnerFramework.TaskException: Could not load file or assembl 'File://\myshare\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyPorject\TestMyProject\bin\Release\TestMyProject.dll' or one of its dependencies.

The tests run with MSTest. I have enabled the option loadFromRemoteSources in devenv.exe.config on Visual Studio 2010 Pro and the Testproject is deployable.

The Problem is the location from which the Test runner tries to read the assembly (file://\)

When i start the project from C:\ it works.

What can i do?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end? if you add a network drive for \myshare\, surely resharper didn't just pick up the drive? did you need to configure resharper to point at the drive?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Find the Jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.*.exe.config files and add the line:

`<loadFromRemoteSources  enabled="true"/>`

To the `<runtime>` section.

[Related to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx) but R# has its own external task runner so it can handle assemblies that are cpu specific (amongst other reasons).

Update: Try adding a drive letter for you share. That worked for me.