# Resharper Test Runner wont run unit tests in VMWare Fusion shared folder

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, vmware-fusion

I've got a VMWare Fusion Windows 7 ultimate VM with VS (2008 & 2010) and Resharper. I tried to move all my solutions to a shared drive on my Mac this morning, and after toggling with some trust issues, everything works fine.

EXCEPT that Resharper's test runner won't pick up my tests. They just stay grayed out.

I've searched everywhere for a solution, but no luck yet.

I DO have a full trust set up for the location that the solution is in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the .NET code execution security settings for the ReSharper test runner.

See [How to configure Resharper 5.1's Test Runner to accept network shares?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283440/how-to-configure-resharper-5-1s-test-runner-to-accept-network-shares/4505291#4505291)

> Find the
>   Jetbrains.resharper.taskrunner.*.exe.config
>   files and add the line:
>
> `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>`
>
> To the  section.

Comment: this has already been done... I quit using shared folder since change tracking didn't work in VS either.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the exact same thing (VMWare Fusion on a Mac with a Windows 7 Enterprise VM having VS2010 and ReSharper 5.1). While the error window was up, I opened task manager to see the process whose name began with "Jetbrains", then right-clicked and opened file location (that way I was sure to have the right config file). After making the recommended addition and restarting VS2010, it worked!